# Problem setting view property of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController whose NIB only contains a UINavigationController. The UINavigationController contains a UIViewController that loads another view from an external NIB.

I am unable to set the File Owner's view property because IB does not hook up to anything. How can I wire up the view property? What do I wire it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have created the property for that viewController ? And did'nt forget to add IBOutlet in the @property line ?

Comment: do I need to create a property for the viewcontroller?